# Cypress click on an nth image in a table with specifc src

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing

I have a list of items in the table, each item has an image , active (blue) and not active (black), how do I make this query for cypress.

This is the image of the table list :
[image]

Then this is the html code for the table :
[image]

When expanded the image is below, it has a src path of `/static/images/icon_profile.png`
[image]

My current test is like this :

```
it('Should create a legal form of a Customer profile', ()=>{
    cy.get('th').eq(50).find('img').should('have.attr', 'src', '/static/images/icon_profile.png').first().click()
  })
```

But when I ran it I get this error :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it more easily by combining selectors

```js
cy.get('tr img[src="/static/images/icon_profile.png"]')
  .first()
  .parent('a')  // click the link not the img
  .click()
```

To confirm you have the right index when using `.eq(50)` run

```js
cy.get('tr img[src="/static/images/icon_profile.png"]')
  .first()
  .parent('tr')
  .invoke('index')  // which row is it?
  .log()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
cy.get('tr').each(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.attr('src') == '/static/images/icon_profile.png') {
    cy.wrap($ele).parent('a').click()
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this passes, but wondering why it doesn't click, it just stays there

Comment: You can add `cy.wrap($ele).click({force: true})`

Comment: Looks like I have to click the anchor tag if you look closely on the image since the image is wrapped under an anchor tag